# IntelliJ Erlang "Cannot find declaration to go to"

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang, intellij-14, erlang-otp

**Setup:**

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2
Erlang plugin 0.11.1144
SDK: Erlang OTP 25, erts-13.0
Project Imported: https://github.com/FlowForwarding/enetconf
```

When I mouse over some variables, I get the message "Cannot find declaration to go to". As a result, I am unable to do a code walk-through. Please help me in resolving the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend you report this issue at https://github.com/ignatov/intellij-erlang/issues Try to clear the IDE caches to see if it helps. (File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart) Make sure that content roots are properly configured https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html

Comment: Thanks @Egor Klepikov. The issue got resolved after configuring Content roots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved after configuring Content roots as explained in  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html. The ContentRoot looked as follows.

[image: ContentRoot]